# C#: Return T from a dictionary which saves Objects

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary, boxing

Is it not ineffective to use for the `Dictionary<Type,object>` instead of `Dictionary<Type,T>` ?

Everytime I add an ICustomerService It gets boxed.

If I would have Type,T there should be no boxing, what do you think?

```
public class MyService
{        
    private static Dictionary<Type, object> _services = new Dictionary<Type, object>();


        public static void AddService<T>(object service)
        {
            if (! (_services.ContainsKey(typeof(T))))
                _services.Add(typeof(T), service);
        }


        public static T1 GetService<T1>()
        {
            return (T1) _services[typeof(T1)];
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you can't be more specific about the value type? Object is kind of a broad category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Everytime I add an ICustomerService It gets boxed.

That would be highly unusual.  Only value type values get boxed.  It is technically possible to have a *struct* implement an interface.  But very uncommon to do so.  The only overhead you got here is the cast.  That's very quick on a reference type and pretty unavoidable by the looks of your snippet.

Comment: oh yes you are right only int,double gets boxed putting into object.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not going to get boxed when you add an `ICustomerService` unless `ICustomerService` is a value type, which would be unusual. (It sounds like an interface.) Boxing only happens with value types.

Basically you're trying to represent a type relationship which can't be expressed in generics. Boxing for value types (and checks elsewhere) are the only way around this. You can't treat the dictionary as a different type of dictionary for each call, depending on what `T` is. Generics simply don't work that way. How would you expect the in-memory representation to work under the hood, with a single object (the dictionary) having a different representation for each value (without boxing, somehow)?

Answer (score 0):

Boxing occurs **only** when you switch between value and reference types.

It means that, in this case, boxing/unboxing occurs only when object is of type `int`, `byte`, `char`, etc.

`ICustomerService` is an interface (I suppose from naming), so it's a reference type. No boxing occurs.

The `GetService` method, instead, performs a type casting, which doesn't affect performance until you have a casting operator overriden.